# Intermittent issue connecting to application server via Hostname

Tags: linux, ip, hostname

I use putty to connect to my application servers, but many times I face issue in connecting to the server via hostname. The error message says, 'Unable to open connection to **my_hostname** Host does not exist'. Sometimes, on restarting the system, the issue gets resolved automatically but many times even on restarting the same problem occurs. This problem does not occur when connecting to the server via IP address. But for many servers I do not have the IP addresses, which creates a problem. I have gone through many such related articles and posts but none helped me out. I am using a company laptop and as of now formatting the system would be a challenge for me. If anybody could help me diagnosing and fixing the issue, it would be great.

Comment: You can find the IP's by doing `nslookup <hostname>`

Comment: Finding the IP's is fine, but isn't there a fix for the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is a DNS problem. If the problem occurs from inside the company network, then you may be getting incorrect nameserver information when your laptop gets an address from the DHCP server. 
If it is from outside the company network, then it is a problem with DNS propogation from inside the network to the public DNS servers.
If the problem only occurs from outside the company network, that is out of your hands. The solution is to find out the IP addresses and add them to your computer's hostfile.
In windows 10 it is located at C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
You can make entries for those hostnames and point them to the proper IP addresses, and you are good to go unless they change those IP addresses in the future.

Comment: But when we are outside company network, not everyone's laptop faces this problem, but only my laptop faces this problem. Also, why does get resolved sometimes.

Comment: I have no answer for that. You can try applying my fix but beyond that, it is very difficult to diagnose an intermittent problem.

Comment: Sure. Will apply it.